# Drupal 8: List taxonomy terms with active class in twig

Tags: templates, twig, nodes, taxonomy, drupal-8

Let say I have a taxonomy name Flavor and the terms have Vanilla, Chocolate and Green Tea.

I also have a content type name ice-cream with flavor field under 'Flavor' taxonomy which can multiple select.

I create a ice-cream page name Baskin Robin and I tick 'Vanilla' and 'Chocolate' under flavor field.

How to list all 'Flavor' terms in node.html.twig and add a class for 'Vanilla' and 'Chocolate'?

For example:

```
<div class="field-item active">Vanilla</div>
<div class="field-item active">Chocolate</div>
<div class="field-item">Green Tea</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a **block** or a **views** to do that.
You can also use a **hook_preprocess_node** to inject all flavors in the ice-cream template.

- [Here the documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/create-a-custom-block) to create a custom block.
- [Here the documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/views/create-a-simple-block-view) to create a views block.
- [Here the documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/block/overview) to place a block (custom or views).

I will explain the easiest & fastest, but most dirty one, to achieve your goal - using the **hook_preprocess_node**.

**I recommend to use the custom block or the views for scalability & maintainability. The code below is a working example, you could use it in a custom block.**

---

Here the code using the preprocess way.

In your `template.theme` file:

```
/**
* Implements hook_preprocess_node.
*/
function template_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];

  if($node->bundle() == 'ice-cream') {
    // Should be injected.
    $termStorage = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term');

    // Load all flavors taxonomy term.
    $variables['flavors'] = $termStorage->loadTree('flavors', 0, NULL, TRUE);
  }
}
```

In your `node.html.twig` or `node--ice-cream.html.twig`:

```
{% for flavor in flavors %}
  {% set classes = ['field-item'] %}
  {% for node_flavor in node.field_flavors if node_flavor.target_id == flavor.id %}
    {% set classes = classes|merge(['active'])%}
  {% endfor %}

  <div class="{{ classes|join(' ') }}">{{ flavor.name.value }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

---

Hope it will help you !

Comment: You are missing a curly bracket in the {{ flavor.name.value}} line.

Comment: Corrected, Thanks !